# Inter process data handling between tcp client thread to active forms

Tags: c#

I have tcp client socket thread which receives data update frequently. what is the best way to store the data and send appropriate data to active forms.

Comment: You’ll have to explain a lot more about what you want to achieve. There’s no one “best” way to “store data.” Store how? Permanently? Temporarily? What data? What are active forms here? How should the data be sent? How to determine “appropriate”? What processes are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP client thread can extract data from TCP socket and do one of the following. Data can be deserialized before passing to active form.

1.Put data(object) in shared data structure like list, queue or stack and raise a event on active form.

2.Put data(object) in shared data structure like list, active form has already subscribed to collection changed event of data structure.

3.Directly raise an event on active form with passing received data(object) as event parameter

~Nilesh